# Function to Set org-hide foreground not working

Tags: faces, org-hide

One issue with themes in Emacs is that they tend not to set the org-hide face properly so that leading stars in headings become visible. I have written a function to set the org-hide foreground to the default background when a theme is enabled, but it is not exactly working.  It works if I invoke it manually but not when invoked in a hook called when a new theme is enabled.  Here is what I have:

```
  (defun ded:set-org-hide ()
    "Make sure that both the background and foreground colors of the org-hide face
      matches the background of the default face."
    (interactive)
    (message "ded:set-org-hide")
    (set-face-attribute 'org-hide nil
                        :foreground
                        (face-attribute 'default :background nil t)))
  (add-hook 'after-enable-theme-hook #'ded:set-org-hide)
```

I know it is getting invoked because I see the message, but it does not set the org-hide face for some reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it do what you expect when you call the function directly? If so, then perhaps the theme code is overriding what it does.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly when called directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around for this that I want to post just in case someone else runs across this.  For some reason, the function works fine if called after a slight delay after enabling a new theme, so I just wrapped the above function in a timer delay:

```
   (defun ded:delay-org-hide ()
     (run-at-time 1 nil #'ded:set-org-hide))
```

Then, call this delayed version in the hook:

```
(add-hook 'after-enable-theme-hook #'ded:delay-org-hide)
```

Now, all is working.